# Android listview search not returning correct corresponding activity for results

Tags: android, search, listview

I have a listview with corresponding activities that start when you click on each item. But when I implement setTextFilterEnabled(true), the results, when clicked, do not start the correct activity. I read something about not using 'position', but what does that mean? How do I correct this?

```
    public class Contactpage extends ListActivity {

private static final int KEYBOARD = 0;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       

    String[] people = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.people_array);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listtest, people));

    ListView lv = getListView(); 
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true); 


    final String[] email = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.details_array);
    final String[] number = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.number_array);

  //Intent after selection is made
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            String contenttt = email[position];
            String contentt = number[position];
            Intent showContent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Viewer.class);

            Bundle b = new Bundle(); 
            b.putString("name",contenttt);
            showContent.putExtras(b);

            Bundle a = new Bundle(); 
            a.putString("number",contentt);
            showContent.putExtras(a);
            startActivity(showContent);
        }});}


    @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
           super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
           menu.add(0, KEYBOARD, 0, R.string.menu_keyboard)
           .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search);
           return true;
       }
    @Override
       public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case KEYBOARD: {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
    Contactpage.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

if (imm != null){
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
}

        return true;}

       default: {
           return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);}
           }
       }

}
```

Comment: Use `position = position - listview.getFirstVisibleItem();` before you start using the position in the rest of the `onitemclickedlistener()`

Comment: eclipse is giving me errors, do i put it right before my setOnItemClickListener? and they suggested i use getFirstVisiblePosition

Comment: put it inside `setOnItemClickListener()` just before you start doing anything.

Comment: hm i get "VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token" for the first 'position'? i placed your line before public void btw. If i place it after, it still does not work

Comment: Maybe there is something faulty with your code logic. Are the `email` and `number` shown on the listview item?

Comment: no they are shown after i click the item and get directed to viewer.class which is another listview populated with email and number

Comment: Try using the `long id` instead of `position`.

Comment: hm then i get Type mismatch: cannot convert from long to int when i String contenttt and contentt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple, found it after hounding around the internet.
Just add:

```
    String name = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    for (int index = 0; index < people.length; index++)
    {
        if (name.equals(people[index]))
        {
            position = index;
            break;
        }
    }
```

inside the onItemClickListener